# Почему не работает кэш первого уровня Hibernate в данном примере?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Вот у меня простейший метод

```
public List<DishResponseDTO> getAll() {
    List<Dish> dishlsit = dishRepository.findAll();
    return dishlsit.stream()
            .map(DishMapper::toDishResponseDTO)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Я его в @SpringBootTest вызываю, но с transactional

```
 @Test
    @Transactional
    public void get() {
        System.out.println(dishService.getAll());
        System.out.println(dishService.getAll());
        System.out.println(dishService.getAll());
    }
```

Разве он не выполняется в одной сессии, если стоит @Transactional?
Почему 3 вызова провоцируют 3 обращения к БД, я думал, что кэш первого уровня hibernate должен решать эти вопросы, если вызовы в границах сессии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кеш первого уровня, грубо говоря, хранит такую структуру данных:

```
Map<EntityId, Object> entityById;
```

Т.е. он позволяет получить сущность по идентификатору. Кеш первого уровня действительно привязан к сессии, которая в свою очередь привязана к транзакции. Но так как кеш первого уровня хранит только мапу идентификаторов, то он не работает, когда выполняется любой другой запрос. Как в этом случае, результат запроса "получить все объекты" не может быть воссоздан из кеша первого уровня.

Для такого нужно использовать кеш второго уровня (который в свою очередь не хранит объекты, а только идентификаторы объектов для запроса).

Кеш первого уровня полезен, чтобы не делать дополнительные запросы именно по идентификатору, например, когда несколько записей в результате ссылается на один и тот же ассоциированный объект.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ, если я правильно понимаю, то получать мы можем только отдельные объекты. Список не получится никак.